# What sites have the code formatting filter enabled?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I know that the code formatting filter ("your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code") is enabled on Stack Overflow.

However, are there any other sites where this filter is enabled? For example, Code Review or Code Golf? Can the code formatting filter be enabled on particular sites on a request basis?

I'm asking because I've seen a few questions about it closed as off-topic as only about a specific site (SO). Are such closures justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently enabled on 4 sites. It probably *should* be enabled on a lot more (for instance, only one out of the four internationalized Stack Overflows has it turned on). It can be easily enabled upon a request from the members of a site that needs it.

Questions regarding the code formatting check should be considered on-topic for any meta if the question is otherwise within that site's scope.

Comment: Which sites are the four?

Comment: @Sonic maybe they keep it a secret to prevent flood of badly formatted questions on the sites without the filter. (i.e. if one knows there is no filter, why bother formatting the code?)

Comment: No, I just don't particularly care to maintain a list. If anyone really wants this, it's trivial to determine if a given site has the check enabled: create a new account and try to post unformatted code.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a list, so I made a list:

- Code Review
- Mathematica
- Software Engineering
- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow in Spanish ("Stack Overflow en español")
- Stack Overflow in Russian ("Stack Overflow на русском")

Some of this information comes from [searching Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not+properly+formatted+as+code%22+-overflow+) for posts on the relevant metas.

Two of these sites, Code Review and Mathematica, also have MathJax enabled.

Comment: I believe it's also enabled on on Software Engineering (as of 2016) and Stack Overflow in Spanish/Stack Overflow en español (as of 2019). [Here's a relevant discussion on the former](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6920/401076) about the feature. Presumably a translated version of the "not properly formatted as code" message appears on SO in Spanish, but searching their Meta isn't returning any obviously relevant results for me.

Comment: Software Engineering definitely has the filter, so apparently, at least *five* sites have it.