# What's wrong in this answer?

Tags: support, indentation

This is a screenshot of an answer I cannot post.
Preview output is okay, the text is okay, I only have one line of a command, anything else.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
The problem is with the bottom links.
[image]
How did I inserted them?
I wrote *MAC Install*, selected the text, clicked on link icon and pasted the URL.   The same as the other 2.

**UPDATE 2:**
So I inserted the links one by one (save Edit after each one).
[image]

It went fine until the last one when the same error was displayed
[image]

**UPDATE 3:**
So I tried to simply paste the URL:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? There's some instructions on how to solve this problem in the top answer to [False positive? I get this error but cannot find any reason: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294841/false-positive-i-get-this-error-but-cannot-find-any-reason-your-post-appears). If you've tried that but still continue to get this error, please let me know.

Comment: I highly suspect it is the italics around the filename. You can also play in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: That or the lack of full line breaks (ie the rendered output is in `<p>`paragraphs rather than `<br>`)

Comment: Making them a bulleted list, `- [Mac Install][1]` etc. should work, extrapolating from Shog's answer at the target.

Comment: Seems it is a must to make a bullet list with more than 2 lines with links. It worked now