# Cannot post question using specific MathJax because of warning about missing code formatting

Tags: bug, reputation, code-formatting, error-message, mathjax

On Mathematica SE, this snippet **couldn't** be submitted as a question

> some text...
>
> some more text....
>
> $$
>
> \rho_h(f)=R_h(f)/R_0(f)
>
> $$

The  error was

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I really couldn't figure out the typo, if any.  Is this a bug? Please help.

---

EDIT: the suggested solution [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294841/false-positive-i-get-this-error-but-cannot-find-any-reason-your-post-appears) is about the use of ` during code formatting which, as far as I know, is mutually exclusive from LaTex formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [False positive? I get this error but cannot find any reason: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294841/false-positive-i-get-this-error-but-cannot-find-any-reason-your-post-appears)

Comment: oh no ..copy paste what i have formatted as code..I am actually not entering as code. Didn't know of mathematica meta...could you please kindly migrate this question there or direct me how to do do myself?

Comment: @Luuklag The question is fine here.

Comment: I *assume* this issue may affect all sites that support MathJax, eg Mathematics, Physics, Astronomy, Chemistry. So it should be on-topic here.

Comment: Can this question get a more descriptive title, so it can be of use to future readers?

Answer (score 4):

This solves it

> $$
>   \rho_h(f)=R_h(f)/R_0(f)$$

instead of

> $$
>   \rho_h(f)=R_h(f)/R_0(f)
>   $$

This is surprising since its **not** a problem on Physics SE.
Hope the Mathematica code checker can be updated to accommodate this, imho, common way of writing.

Comment: The "appears to contain code" warning checker is related to the user's low reputation. Since you have high enough reps on Physics.SE, you possibly won't get the warning.

Comment: > *This is surprising since its not a problem on Physics SE*.
That's because Physics SE doesn't have that triggering filter.