# MathJax bugs "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted"

Tags: bug, code-formatting, mathjax

**V1**: complains

```
$$
\frac{x}{y}
$$
```

**V2**: doesn't

```
$$\frac{x}{y}$$
```

**V3**: complains

```
$$\begin{align}
  & \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \\
  & \frac{y}{x} + \frac{x}{y} \\
\end{align}$$
```

I favor working with V1; V2 isn't a big deal, but V3 is - I write my LaTeX like I write my code, not like an egg salad. Also, it wasn't easy to narrow down to MRE.

Networks that have this format checker are pain to work with. It's not up to users to understand bugs in a detector. Questions (not covered in duplicates from what I skimmed, I checked all):

1. Why V2 works but V1 doesn't?
2. Why V2 works but V3 doesn't? Is it possible to write vertically-aligned LaTeX, like clean code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erroneous "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366625/erroneous-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-c)

Comment: @MartinR that is not a duplicate.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99: Is it not? Both here and there it is observed that `$$<newline><formula><newline>$$` produces an error message, and removing those newlines fixes the problem.

Comment: Somewhat a duplicate, but there may be more to this, I'll check back sometime soon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code formatting error message dispenses no-longer-true advice, and doesn't indicate what to do in case of false positives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349595/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342761/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294843/282094

Comment: Thanks for the references; I've not found the "why" in them, but if I missed it, let me know. I doubt they address my Q2 though, but I could open that separately if needed. And if I did miss it, it wasn't easy to find, so it favors future readers to post a short answer re-explaining or just quoting.