# Asking how to format code blocks on SOF because I am prohibited from commenting on an existing post

Tags: support, code-formatting, error-message

I am getting this warning when proofreading a question:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Obviously, I used the help (?) icon and an existing Stack Exchange question to find some options for formatting. After trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on each individual line of code, selecting all and using the code block tool on the toolbar and indenting each line with four spaces, none of these methods allowed me to continue and post my question.

Why would this be? Should I try to just use some other method like tilde fencing?

Comment: Did you try using the binary search method [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294843/377214)? Try cutting out blocks of your post until you find the part that triggers the error. Once you find it, please edit your question here with the Markdown that triggered the error.

Comment: Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog, thank you for the advice! It turns out the error was triggered by a compiler error message I copied and pasted into the body of my question.

Comment: When in doubt, format compiler error messages like code. They're often written specifically with the expectation that they'll be displayed in a console window, so they'll look better in that typesetting.